# How can I use {{this}} as a parameter in a dbt jinja macro?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

How can I pass the name of the current model using {{this}} as a parameter for a macro in a config function?

I have tried a couple of options and none of them works.
model/Table1.sql

{{ config(post_hook= calculate_test("{{this}}") ) }}

macro/calculate_test.sql

```
{% macro calculate_test(tableN) %}
   
    {%- set tableName = tableN -%}

    {% set sql %}

        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM {{ tableName }}

    {% endset %}

    {% set results = run_query(sql) %}

{% endmacro %}
```

The error is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there! Only thing is that you’ve got extra curly brackets and misplaced quotes. The entire config block is Jinja so you don’t need the curly brackets around ‘this’.

```
{{ config(post_hook= “calculate_test(this)” ) }}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Unfortunetly didn't work neither in this way. However it worked like this:         "{{calculate_test(this)}}"

Comment: good to hear. is your usage inside a `{{ config(...) }}` block like you gave in the question? because if it isn't, it makes sense why you have `{{` around the macro name. might be worth editing your question for future folks -- it's a hard aspect of Jinja to understand!

Comment: yes, the macro is inside the config() as in the above example; however without adding brackets when I was running the model, the macro does not get executed, that's why I've added them

Comment: weird! so you have curly brackets around config and curly brackets around your macro statement? did expect to see that, but maybe that's the case. I'll do some testing and update my answer, though it sounds as if you're right.

Comment: indeed, I have 2x sets of curly brackets: {{ config( post_hook= "{{calculate_test(this)}}") }}

Comment: Hey! I'm facing a similar issue. I'm trying to pass something like this: {{config(alias='{{ this.schema }}')}}. But without success. How did you do it, in the end?

Comment: In my case, it works like  pre_hook="{{grant_select(this.schema, this.name)}}",
BTW no pre_hook="{{grant_select(this)}}" allowed, args can be the strings only.
dbt 1.5.0